# Using Alarm Manager to Start a Service

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have some code I want to execute at 3:00am every day. I've read the [Service Class Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and it seems I can use AlarmManager to fire an intent(Activity or Service, I think?), and then, in that intent create and post a message in the Android Notification area.

```
Calendar threeAM = Calendar.getInstance();
threeAM.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,2);
threeAM.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
threeAM.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
threeAM.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
AlarmManager alarmManager =
         (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, myNotifier.class);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, threeAM.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, i , 0));
Log.i("Service TEST", "Alarm set?" );
```

It runs through the code with no problems, but there is no indication that the alarm is set, and the activity doesn't start. I'm using an activity that I know works. I tried wrapping it in a try/catch, nothing in logcat...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should register your activity to receive boot broadcast receivers so that your application starts on the moment the OS boot up complete. here is the link http://www.androidenea.com/2009/09/starting-android-service-after-boot.html

It will not help in terms of notification but yes it will solve your problem of activity not starting...

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only work if you execute it before 3am. Otherwise, you will be setting an alarm in the past.

Comment: I've tried setting it to just a few minutes ahead when I was testing it. It seems the start time should launch the activity the first time, and then repeating on the interval argument, is that right? Is there a way to check what alarms are set?

Comment: @cinqoTimo: "It seems the start time should launch the activity the first time, and then repeating on the interval argument, is that right?" -- yes, though I have never used `AlarmManager` to start an activity. "Is there a way to check what alarms are set?" -- the alarms are buried in the `dumpsys` output somewhere. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands